# How to move one file from a directory to another no R using just a part of the file name?

Tags: r, file-copying

I'm trying to find a code that moves a file from one directory to another using only a part of the name, this is because the file is generated daily and only a part of the file name is constant (the rest varies each day without a defined pattern).

An example of one file I want to move is this (using `list.files` command):

```
> list.files("V:/evfilesce9i9/apps9/vbe9/dep4/KFTP/KFTP001D_FicherosCeca", "EnviaCecaReservedLimit")
[1] "EnviaCecaReservedLimit_0239_PRO_201711172000331.csv"
```

I tried `file.rename()` but I am not able to find the way to use only a partial string of the name to move it with this command.

clarification: I'm aiming just to MOVE the file from one directory to another, not to rename it, I want the name of the file to be the same in the destination directory as it is in the original directory

Could anyone help me?

Comment: what about searching for files with the given pattern in their names first and moving the found ones?

Comment: Please show us an example of the filenames, use `list.files()`, we can then provide a `regex` to identify the files you want and extract the part of the name you want to use for the new filename.

Comment: I used the code you provided me @Grisha, so it's also useful to provide an example @Manuel Bickel:

`> list.files("V:/evfilesce9i9/apps9/vbe9/dep4/KFTP/KFTP001D_FicherosCeca", "CUADREOPERACIONES")
[1] "CUADREOPERACIONES_0239_PRO_20171117.html"`

The final part is not the current date though it seems it.

Comment: Thanks for the example, could you please show the name of a second file and how the new file names should look like (to avoid duplicate filenames). Please do this as an edit to your question, not as a comment. Easier for others to follow the discussion then... Its easy to eliminate the date part in your filenames and replace it, e.g., by a number.

Comment: Just edited with a clarification based to your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this is what you need. (use a test directory and test files for testing)

```
setwd("C:/currentdir/")

newdir <- "C:/newdir"

currentdir <- getwd()

files <- list.files(path = currentdir, full.names = TRUE)

files_new <- gsub(dirname(files[1]), newdir, files)

for (i in 1:length(files)) {

  file.copy(files[i], files_new[i])

}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but easy to adapt for my needs. Thanks for help @Manuel Bickel

Comment: Sorry for not understanding you correclty. I am glad that I could provide some code that you can adapt at least.